# How to trigger mouse click prgrammatically in vaadin ? button.click() isn't doing the job

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

I am trying to create a custom pagination and below is small part of the logic. When clicking the ">" button it should change the page i.e click the next page's button programmatically. I tried button.click() but it isn't working for me either. I am new to vaadin so please help.

```
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++) {            
        Button b = v.get(i);
        b.addClickListener(e->{
            if(b.getCaption()==">") {
                if(page%5==0) {

                    final int mn = Math.min(v.size()-2,page+5);
                    grid.removeAllComponents();

                    grid.addComponent(pre, 2, 3);
                    int j = 1;
                    for(j=1;j<mn-page+1;j++) {
                        grid.addComponent(v.get(page + j-1),3+j,3);
                    }
                    grid.addComponent(ne, j+4, 3);


                }
                bt = v.get(page);
                bt.click();

                page++;
            }
            else if(b.getCaption()=="<") {
                if(page%5==1) {
                    grid.removeAllComponents();                        
                    grid.addComponent(pre, 2, 3);
                    int j = 1;
                    for(j=5;j>0;j--) {
                        grid.addComponent(v.get(page - j-1),9-j,3);
                    }
                    grid.addComponent(ne, 10, 3);
                }
                page--;
            }
            else{
                page=Integer.parseInt(b.getCaption());
            }



            if(page==v.size()-2) ne.setEnabled(false);
            else ne.setEnabled(true);

            if(page==1) pre.setEnabled(false);
            else pre.setEnabled(true);
          });


    }
```

Comment: `click()` will do that (unless you hide some further context here). Yet, relying on button names and reuse the functionionalty of a listener there is brittle anyway.  Write yourself some proper functions, that do the paging (e.g. `goto(page)`, `next()`, ...) and just call them from the buttons.

Comment: In addition to what @cfrick mentioned, why do you want to programmatically call the ">"? What is your use case? As far as pagination works, your ">" button should react to the used clicking it, as in when he clicks it, the next page is displayed, what am I missing?

Comment: `b.getCaption()==">"`is not the correct way for comparing strings. Use `equals()`